# How to derive (mathematically and intuitively) the relationship between expected price level and natural rate of employment?

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, natural-rate-unemployment, comparative-statics

We know that
$ W = \mathbb{E}(P)f(u, z) $
, so that nominal wage $ W / P = (\mathbb{E}(P) / P)f(u, z) $

From Blanchard.

Furthermore,

$ W / P = 1/(1+m) $ (where m is defined as the markup on wages to prices $ P = (1+m)W $ )

By definition, if $ \mathbb{E}(P) = P $, then $ u = u_n $, so $ Y = Y_n $,
as where $Y$ is some production function $Q$ of total workers $N$ (ignoring capital),  $Y = Q(N), 
 N = Q^{-1}(Y) $, and $ u = 1 - (Q^{-1}(Y) / L)$, so $u$ and therefore $f(u, \bar{z})$ map directly to a $Y$

But how do changes in $ \mathbb{E}(P) $ affect things?

If $ \mathbb{E}(P) < P $, then apparently $ Y_n < Y $

**Where do we get this from?**

I understand that if $ \mathbb{E}(P) < P $, then nominal wage becomes $ W / P = (\mathbb{E}(P) / P)f(u, z) < f(u, z) $, but how does this mean that **output** decreases? How do we get from lowering the expected value of P to a lower Y_natural, and causally (intuitively) how does this work?

Sidenote: I understand this has something to do with the aggregate supply curve, and since it's upward sloping, if P decreases, Y must also decrease, but I don't get that mathematically or causally.